# Is there a way to trigger a razer macro using python?

Tags: python, macros, pyautogui

Hello I'm trying to create a python script that sends a key press using pyautogui and I want that key press to use the macro that i configured in razer synapse.

Comment: does synapse register the key press? If so, it should trigger the macro already?

Comment: I think that's my problem, synapse doesn't register the key press sent by pyautogui. Any suggestions on how I can do it?

Comment: I guess the Python interface does not trigger the event, because it by passes the mouse driver comipletely. Instead it sends the event somehow directly to another interface. So there is no chance to trigger it using pyautogui, but instead using another interface.